# List function listing all the characters seperately

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

So i want to convert tuples to a list here, but there are still some things i need to do before that.

```
string = "'!GAMESTATE', ('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')"
lst = list(string)
for x in lst:
    print(x)
```

So the output should become a list:
[('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')]

I need to remover the most outer quotemarks (") and I also need to remove the '!GAMESTATE'

Comment: Please tell us what is the exact expected output. Also you might want to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: well i tried to use string.strip(""), but that doesn't work. The output should be: [('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Where is this input coming from? Did you create it yourself? It looks it should be stored as json.

Comment: I tried making my own gameserver with encode and decode. I have never used json, but I'll look into it thank you @ekhumoro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You san use the function `eval` to convert your string to a tuple.
Then you can use slicing to remove the first element of this tuple, i.e. '!GAMESTATE'.
Then you can convert the tuple to a list with `list()`.
Finally it gives the following one-line code, with no need of `import` directive:

```
s = "'!GAMESTATE', ('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')"
result = list(eval(s)[1:])
print(result) # [('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')]
```

Comment: A note on this: eval should never be used on an input that could be unsafe. Because it simply executes whatever string it is provided, it may leave you open to exploitation and attack.

Comment: In this case because you know the input is "safe", `eval` is OK and so I upvoted it. But in general `ast.literal_eval` should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great "tricks" is `ast.literal_eval` applied to a string expression:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

This is also safer to use than `eval` when the input is "questionable."

```
import ast

string = "'!GAMESTATE', ('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')"

t = ast.literal_eval(string)
l = list(t[1:]) # ignore '!GAMESTATE'
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[('0', '2.0', '10.0'), ('1', '0.0', '10.0'), ('2', '1.0', '11.0')]
```

Comment: thank you man, I have no idea what it does but it works :)